# Where do I put GeoDjango LayerMapping definitions in a Django project?

Tags: django, geodjango

GeoDjango uses `LayerMapping` classes to define mappings from spatial data formats like shapefile to models. Where do should I place those inside a project? Can they be used from a data migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) or a data migration to import your data.